# PHP - elegant way to check if assoc array value has a subarray?

Tags: php, associative-array

Is there any elegant way to check if

`$review['passenger']` has any `$review['passenger']['*']`?

Comment: What about `is_array()`?

Comment: if( is_array($review['passenger']) ) { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `is_array()`. It will check if it is an array or not -

```
if(is_array($review['passenger'])) {
   // is an array
}
```

Or if you want to check if some `key` is present or not then -

```
if(array_key_exists('key', $review['passenger'])) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe Danius was using "`['*']`" to reference "*one or more sub-arrays*", instead of specifying it as "*the*" sub-array.

About his question, the only way to verify if a specific KEY of your array has sub-arrays is checking its sub-items, one by one, to identify if any one of them is an array.

It may not be "*elegant*", but it is definitively functional:

```
function has_array($arr) {
   $has_array = false;
   foreach ($arr as $item):
      if (is_array($item)):
          $has_array = true;
          break;
      endif;
   endforeach;
   return $has_array;
}
```

Simply call the function this way:

```
$result = has_array($review['passenger']);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_key_exists`:

```
$array = array(
    "passenger" => array(
        "*" => "ok"    
    )     
);

if(array_key_exists('*', $array['passenger'])){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "not ok";
}
```