# PHP array inside array and non-array access

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

The following array is taken from a bank's account transactions web service.
I need to check if the field named **SwiftKodu** exists or not. If there is, I will save its value **(EFT)** to the database.
There is an array as below.

```
["Details"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["KeyValueOfstringstring"]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(9) "SwiftKodu"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(3) "EFT"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(16) "EftSorguNumarasi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(6) "000000"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(22) "GonderenKimlikNumarasi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(10) "000000000"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(19) "AliciKimlikNumarasi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(12) "EftIslemTuru"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(3) "M01"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(11) "GonderenAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(58) "GonderenAdi"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(8) "AliciAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(41) "AliciAdi"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(17) "GonderenBankaKodu"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(3) "000"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(16) "GonderenBankaAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(16) "GonderenBankaAdi"
      }
      [9]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(16) "GonderenSubeKodu"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(5) "00000"
      }
      [10]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(15) "GonderenSubeAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(16) "IBAN MERKEZ SUBE"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(20) "GonderenIbanKumarasi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(26) "TR000000000000000000000"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(14) "AliciBankaKodu"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(2) "15"
      }
      [13]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(13) "AliciBankaAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(33) "AliciBankaAdi"
      }
      [14]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(12) "AliciSubeAdi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(17) "AliciSubeAdi"
      }
      [15]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(13) "AliciSubeKodu"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(3) "000"
      }
      [16]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(22) "EftIlgiliSorguNumarasi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [17]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(20) "EftIlgiliSorguTarihi"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [18]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(10) "OdemeAmaci"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(2) "99"
      }
      [19]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(16) "EftIlgiliIslemNo"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Sometimes just a array comes like this;
When I want to access with foreach,
There are index numbers in the first array I shared. 0,1,2,3...
But since only "SwiftKodu" is sent in the array below, there is no index number and I can't access it with foreach :(

```
**"["Details"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["KeyValueOfstringstring"]=>
     array(2) {
       ["Key"]=>
       string(9) "SwiftKodu"
       ["Value"]=>
       string(3) "CHG"
     }
   }"**
```

Suppose we have assigned the first shared array to the $data variable.

```
echo $data['Details']['KeyValueOfstringstring']['0']['Value'];
```

This way I can print "EFT" on the screen or add it to the database.
But we have sent the array index value as a constant variable.
The field with `"SwiftKodu"` has index 0. (For now)
**The data coming from the web service does not always have 0 index.**

> What I want is this:
> Have I received a 'SwiftCode' from the web service?

p.s: this is a Laravel project.
Thanks!

I tried foreach but failed with only singleton "SwiftCode" incoming arrays.
I tried many functions.
I tried Laravel functions but it didn't work :(

Comment: Welcome to SO ... show what you have attempted

Comment: $detail = $activity['Detaylar']['KeyValueOfstringstring'];
         for($i = 0; $i < count($detail); $i++){
          if($detail[$i]['Key'] == 'SwiftKodu'){
           echo 'var';
          }
         }

Comment: that would be a `for` loop, can you show the `foreach` loop ... edit your question and add the code

Comment: Typically, with a [mcve] we don't need 20 of anything.  Can your sample data be simplified to 4 or 5 entries?  I presume so.  Please always present your PHP array data as `var_export()` output text.  Is this not as simple as `if (isset($activity['Detaylar']['KeyValueOfstringstring']['Key'])) { // not indexed } else { // indexed, use a loop }`?  Adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30570886/2943403).

Comment: You can use the `Illuminate\Support\Arr` helpers to check if this array contains what you need.

Comment: hi @beginnerDeveloper,
Try this hope this will useful for you.

**$result_array = [];            
foreach ($baseArr["Details"]["KeyValueOfstringstring"] as $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array("SwiftKodu",$value))
    {
        array_push($result_array,$value["Value"]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_array);**

Comment: @Piyush Sapariya
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => EFT
)
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => EFT
)
string(56) "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given"

Thanks for your reply.

**"["Details"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["KeyValueOfstringstring"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Key"]=>
        string(9) "SwiftCode"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(3) "CHG"
      }
    }"**

It gave an error because a array came in the above way.